# I can read data from the Firebase RTDB although the user did not sign in or already signed out - security rules do not apply

Tags: c#, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

EDIT: Added shortened classes to provide more information. I have cut out everything which has nothing to do with the problematic Firebase requests and replaced it with [...].

I am trying to set up the security rules for my first Unity/Firebase project and I am facing the problem that I can read data although the user did not sign in or already signed out.
I am afraid I miss something.

Here are my Firebase rules:

```json
"users": {
  "$user_id": {
    // grants write access to the owner of this user account // whose uid must exactly match the key ($userId)
    ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid",
    ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
  }
```

---

EDITED TEXT:

Here is my FirebaseManagerAuth class (responsible for registration and login):

```
[...]

public class FirebaseManagerAuth : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static FirebaseManagerAuth instance;
    [SerializeField] private PlayerDataSO playerData;

    [Header("Firebase")]
    public DependencyStatus dependencyStatus;
    public FirebaseAuth fbAuth;
    public FirebaseUser fbUser;


    void Awake()
    {
        InitializeFirebase();

        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
            //Debug.Log("FirebaseManagerAuth - awake - instance was null ");
        }
        else if (instance != null)
        {
            //Debug.Log("Instance already exists, destroying object!");
            Destroy(this);
        }
    }


    private void InitializeFirebase()
    {
        try
        {
            fbAuth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Gotcha - AUTH! " + e.Message);
        }
        if (fbAuth == null)
            Debug.LogError("INIT FirebaseManagerAUTH + fbAuth = null");
        else
            Debug.Log("INIT FirebaseManagerAUTH + sucessfull");
    }

    

    //Function for the sign out button
    public void SignOut()
    {
        fbAuth.SignOut();
        Debug.Log("Signed out");
    }

    public async Task<string> LoginAwait(string email, string password)
    {
        FirebaseUser user = null;
        try
        {
            //Call the Firebase auth signin function passing the email and password
            user = await fbAuth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password);
            Debug.Log("LoginAwait - Login successful! User-ID: " + user.UserId + " DisplayName: " + user.DisplayName);
            playerData.PlayerName = user.DisplayName;
            playerData.PlayerDBUserId = user.UserId; 
            return null; 
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            FirebaseException authEx = ex.InnerExceptions[0] as FirebaseException;
            if (authEx != null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Login fehlgeschlagen: " + authEx.Message);
                switch (authEx.ErrorCode)
                {
                    case (int)AuthError.MissingEmail:
                        return ("Missing Email");
                    case (int)AuthError.MissingPassword:
                        return ("Missing Password");
                    case (int)AuthError.WrongPassword:
                        return ("Wrong Password");
                    case (int)AuthError.InvalidEmail:
                        return ("Invalid Email");
                    case (int)AuthError.UserNotFound:
                        return ("Account does not exist");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("LoginAwait - unknown error: " + ex.Message);
                return ("unknown login error");
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Here my FirebaseManagerGame (responsible for the read/write operations to the realtime database):

```
[...]

public class FirebaseManagerGame : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static FirebaseManagerGame instance;
    [SerializeField] private PlayerDataSO playerData;

    [Header("Firebase")]
    public DependencyStatus dependencyStatus;
    public DatabaseReference DBreference;



    void Awake()
    {
        InitializeFirebase();

        if (instance == null)
        {
            //Debug.Log("FirebaseManagerGame - awake - instance was null");
            instance = this;
        }
        else if (instance != null)
        {
            //Debug.Log("Instance already exists, destroying object!");
            Destroy(this);
        }
        Debug.Log("FirebaseManagerGame - instance: " + instance.ToString());
    }


    private void InitializeFirebase()
    {

        //Debug.Log("INIT FirebaseManagerGAME START");
        try
        {
            DBreference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Gotcha - GAME! " + e.Message);
            throw e;
        }
        Debug.Log("INIT FirebaseManagerGAME -> DBreference: " + DBreference.ToString());
    }


   


    public void TestReadDB_Button()
    {
        _ = TestReadDB();
    }

    public async Task TestReadDB()
    {
        Debug.Log("FirebaseManagerGame TestReadDB START"); 

        if (FirebaseManagerAuth.instance.fbAuth.CurrentUser != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("FirebaseManagerGame TestReadDB - DB User ID: " + FirebaseManagerAuth.instance.fbAuth.CurrentUser);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Nothing there, especially not CurrentUser -> good or bad...?");
        }

        DataSnapshot snapshot = await DBreference.Child("users").Child(playerData.PlayerDBUserId).Child("levelPassed").Child("easy").GetValueAsync();

        foreach (DataSnapshot mainLevelSnapshot in snapshot.Children)
        {
            Debug.Log("mainLevelSnapshot Key: " + mainLevelSnapshot.Key);
        }
    }
}
```

Now to 3 scenarios I can observe, 2 good and 1 bad.

**Scenario 1 - Good** - Start with the login scene, do the login -> and the authentication

```
FirebaseManagerAuth -> LoginAwait(...))
button -> FirebaseManagerGame -> TestReadDB_Button()
button -> FirebaseManagerAuth -> SignOut()
button ->  FirebaseManagerGame -> TestReadDB_Button()
```

Debug output:

```
FirebaseManagerGame TestReadDB START
FirebaseManagerGame TestReadDB - DB User ID: Mi7Gp6joqjgAYHNiLHrfgOInZbU2
mainLevelSnapshot Key: 1
Signed out
FirebaseManagerGame TestReadDB START
Nothing there, especially no CurrentUser -> good or bad...?
Listen at users/Mi7Gp6joqjgAYHNiLHrfgOInZbU2/levelPassed/easy failed: Permission denied
```

**Scenario 2 - Good** - start directly with the MainMenu_Map-Level scene, hence without the login (which does not happen when using the real app, but very helpful for developing of course and in this case to test the Firebase security rules in the case of an unauthenticated action)

```
button -> FirebaseManagerGame -> TestReadDB_Button()
```

Debug output (no user-id and permission denied -> as expected!):

```
FirebaseManagerGame TestReadDB START
Nothing there, especially no CurrentUser -> good or bad...?
Listen at users/Mi7Gp6joqjgAYHNiLHrfgOInZbU2/levelPassed/easy failed: Permission denied
```

**Scenario 3 - Bad** - start again directly with the MainMenu_Map-Level scene. It is exactly the same approach as in Scenario 2, just another start of the scene! But the following debug output shows the random and errornous behaviour which I do not understand.

```
button -> FirebaseManagerGame -> TestReadDB_Button()
```

Debug output (no user-id BUT the DB read is successful?!?):

```
FirebaseManagerGame TestReadDB START
Nothing there, especially no CurrentUser -> good or bad...?
mainLevelSnapshot Key: 1
```

Comment: Your security rule requires the user to be signed in with Firebase Authentication in order for them to be able to read (only) their own data. But the code you shared is not enough for us to determine why that is not doing what you expected. I recommend logging the UID of the current user right before you access the database. If that doesn't allow you to solve the problem yourself yet, edit your question to show the updated code (hopefully a few more lines than now) and its log output (i.e. the UID).

Comment: Hello Frank, I tried to keep it as short as possible because I was afraid that otherwise no one would read such a long post. But your are right, it was too short now. I hope I found a happy medium and thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: Yeah, now it's indeed a bit much for us to go through. Instead of sharing your entire existing, consider creating a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from scratch and sharing that.

Comment: Okay, it was probably too late yesterday evening ;-) Now, I have thrown away everything which does not have to do with the test logic which leads to the problem or the initializing of the Firebase connection. This should be the same as setting up a whole now project, but the latter would have taken much longer.